# How to create a debian install media with custom packages?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, simple-cdd

I already saw that kind of questions but with no real answer. I'd like to build a Debian stretch installation media (with simple-cdd) that ships with stretch-backports packages. I could only go with adding the backports repository in the preseed configuration file but it wouldn't be usable with offline devices. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems there's no easy way (given the easy-way is simple-cdd) to fine tune the packages shipped with a debian installer media. One could actually customize its repository given it resolves all the dependencies one way or another. (see : [Building a Custom CD Set](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD#Building_a_Custom_Debian_CD_Set))

However, for the particular backports case one could use in its simple-cdd configuration (profiles/[profile].conf) the parameters :

```
backports=true
backports_packages="[package_list_with_dependencies]"
```

Comment: These backport options work for me, are they documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to generate list of packages just put it to `simple-cdd` profile `.downloads` file. These packages, together with the dependencies, will be included into `/pool/main/` directory of resulting image `.iso` file.

https://wiki.debian.org/Simple-CDD/Howto

Comment: Yet this only works with current release repository and not with added ones.